# How to check App URL Id in new Azure portal?

Tags: azure, jwt, azure-active-directory

I registered a new App in Azure AD. It asked for - App Name, Sign On URL, Error URL, Logout URL and Reply URL. It did not ask for an App URL while registering the app.
Where can I locate the App URL Id in this newly registered App? When I am trying to access the App( Web API) using a client application with Client Id & Secret, I am using the App Id instead of App URL. I want to be able to use the App URL in the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is where you can find the App ID URI for your application using the UX of different Microsoft Application Portals:

https://manage.windowsazure.com/

1. Active Directory
2. < Tenant >
3. Applications Tab
4. < Application >
5. Configure Tab
6. Single Sign-On Section
   [image]

https://portal.azure.com/

1. App Registrations
2. < Application >
3. Manifest Tab
4. Edit Manifest Blade
5. "identifierUris"
   [image]

https://identity.microsoft.com

1. At the time of this post, the Identity Portal does not yet support adding App ID URI

I hope this helps!